# AND Query using Elastic Search Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

How do we query elastic document using Java API.

For E.g Consider following Type **'Employee'** which has below values

```
{ "name" : "Jhon" , "department": "IT" , "passport":"XXXXXXX" }
{ "name" : "Sathish" , "department": "IT" }
{ "name" : "Mike" , "department": "Admin" , "passport":"YYYYYYYY" }
{ "name" : "July" , "department": "IT" ,"passport":"ZZZZZZ"}
```

Now, We need to query the the index **to find 'IT' employees who has passport** (like department == "IT" AND passport exists ).

How do achieve this using Elastic Search Java API ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code for searchrequest query builder and it's response.

```
SearchRequestBuilder searchRequest = client.prepareSearch("employees")
            .setPostFilter(FilterBuilders.andFilter(
                    FilterBuilders.termFilter("department", "it"),
                    FilterBuilders.existsFilter("passport")
            ));
SearchResponse searchResponse = searchRequest.get();
```

Rather than using an "and filter" to find the documents with 'IT' department who have passport.

I would suggest you to use aggregation to find the employees who have passport.